Python and lightweight_charts: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop
I'm running the following code in VSC notebook:
from ipynb.fs.full.tool_read_db import get_table2df_pastdays
from lightweight_charts import Chart

table = get_table2df_pastdays('BTCUSDTBB5m',10,1)
table.rename(columns={'openDateTime':'date'},inplace=True)
table.head()
    date    open    high    low close   volume
0   2024-09-05 18:15:00 56052.6 56109.5 55962.0 55995.5 482.592
1   2024-09-05 18:20:00 55995.5 56232.5 55940.5 56203.8 804.477
2   2024-09-05 18:25:00 56203.8 56294.5 56151.4 56173.2 761.775
3   2024-09-05 18:30:00 56173.2 56214.0 56044.7 56135.2 567.344
4   2024-09-05 18:35:00 56135.2 56325.8 56135.2 56206.0 732.861

chart = Chart()
chart.set(table.iloc)
chart.show(block=True)

I'm getting following error:
----> 3 chart.show(block=True)

RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop

Function get_table2df_pastdays just queries the table using SQL Alchemy and spits it out in the form of a Pandas DataFrame. So table is a DataFrame object.
I've tried methods from this thread marked as a solution and wrapping my code generating chart in async main or asyncio.run, but none of this works. What's funny is that the chart popup with caldlestick chart does pop up with correct data only to immediately throw the error I've pasted.
How to tackle this issue ?
